# Postgres find the incorrect datapoint

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am inserting a bunch of values into a table from an external csv that I got from somewhere. My table columns are expected to be:

```
     Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 name              | text                        | 
 info              | text                        | 
 other             | text                        | 
 value1            | numeric(6,3)                | 
 value2            | numeric                     | 
 someOtherValue    | numeric(6,3)                | 
 timestampX        | timestamp without time zone | 

db=# refresh materialized view <table_name>;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2001-09-07 16:30:00.000"
```

I imagine there is an issue with the file I am importing from. How could I find the problematic row?

Comment: fixed, my typo, sorry

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the select statement of your materialized view.